# Python Memory Error while iterating to a big range

Tags: python, python-2.7

```py
total = 0
x = 2**32
for i in range(x):
    total = total + i;
print(total)
```

I am getting a `MemoryError` while looping to a range of `2**32`. Is there any way to do the iteration without running out of memory?

Comment: Try `xrange` instead

Comment: I'm guessing that you meant to print `sum` at the end, otherwise you'll just end up printing `2**32`

Comment: The easy answer is to switch to Python 3, it's implementation of `range` is much smarter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what happens when you try to create a list that contains the first 2<sup>32</sup> non-negative integers (I'm using Python 2.7.11 on a Windows 10 system):

```
>>> for i in range(2**32): pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: range() result has too many items
```

One might expect that if the problem is to have such a large number of items simultaneously in memory, the solution could be that of handling one item at a time through a generator... but it is not:

```
>>> for i in xrange(2**32): pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

The documentation of [xrange()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) built-in function explains why this error occurs:

> **CPython implementation detail**: xrange() is intended to be simple and fast. Implementations may impose restrictions to achieve this. The C implementation of Python restricts all arguments to native C longs (“short” Python integers), and also requires that the number of elements fit in a native C long.

The issue is that 2<sup>32</sup> cannot be passed as an input argument to `xrange` because that number is greater than the **maximum "short" integer in Python**. Try this to convince yourself:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxint       # 2**31 - 1
2147483647
>>> sys.maxint + 1   # 2**31 is automatically converted to "long" int
2147483648L
>>> 2**31
2147483648L
```

You could use nested for loops if you need to repeatedly perform a computation more than 2<sup>31</sup> times (2<sup>34</sup> times in the following example):

```
>>> loops = 0
>>> for i in xrange(2**4):
...    for j in xrange(2**30):
...        # do stuff
...        loops += 1
...
>>> loops
17179869184L
>>> 2**34
17179869184L
```

The code above is a rather naïve workaround. A **while** loop seems to be a much more adequate solution:

```
>>> loops = 0
>>> while loops < 2**34:
...    # do stuff
...    loops += 1
...
>>> loops
17179869184L
```

Comment: The `range` function in Python 3 works like Python 2's `xrange`, but works with integers of any size.

Answer (score 3):

1. `range` creates a list in memory. Use `xrange` to get a generator object which gives you one number in a time.
2. There are better ways to sum a range of numbers from `1` to `n`, for example `(n(n+1))/2`.

Comment: Yes (n(n+1))/2 is better but I am testing if I can do looping to that extent that's y ,Thank You

Answer (score 2):

For a brute-force approach, try this:

```
x = sum(i for i in xrange(2**32))
```

The above will be more efficient, as it uses `xrange` to generate the numbers lazily, and it also uses a generator expression with `sum()` to avoid generating temporary data that gets discarded immediately.

But that will still take some time, as `2**32` is a big number. The smart way to solve this problem is to use a formula, as suggested by @DeepSpace:

```
n = 2**32 - 1
x = (n * (n + 1)) / 2
```